# How to add speed gauge animation to video

Tags: rendering, animation, video

I am slowing down a portion of a video within blender using the speed multiplier. I would like a visualisation displayed in the video of how much it is being slowed down by.

For instance: Speed = 50%...

This value would then adapt to the actual speed of the video as it is played.

Is this possible? Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: yes, it it possible, but not with vanilla Blender. Maybe there is an add-on for that, but for sure you could solve it with a python script